# How can I use my C7 to Euro cable to power a Marshall stanmore 2 speaker in my car?

Tags: electrical, car, speakers, adapt

I have a C7 to Euro cable to give my Marshall stanmore 2 power, now I want to use the Marshall box in my car. Is there a way I can connect or somehow give it power?

I presume I'd need some sort of adapter. I'm searching online but cant really find anything.
[image: C7 TO euro cable]

[image]

Click [here](https://www.marshallheadphones.com/gb/en/stanmore-ii-bluetooth.html)!

Comment: you need to give more information,what voltage is the speaker 12v-110v-220v?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an AC/DC car adapter that can support up to 60 W.

Automotive electrical systems are DC, while these speakers expect AC input.